javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
2024-05-28 03:19:10,175, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] DEBUG DocumentMIDAOImpl Enter get business case id method
2024-05-28 03:19:10,187, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] DEBUG DocumentMIDAOImpl business case ID is :260341
2024-05-28 03:19:10,187, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] DEBUG DocumentMIDAOImpl Enter get business case id method
2024-05-28 03:19:10,193, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] DEBUG DocumentMIDAOImpl business case ID is :260342
2024-05-28 03:19:10,194, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] INFO  UploadDocMDBDelegate Oacr Doc ID 0
2024-05-28 03:19:10,194, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] DEBUG IndexDocumentServiceWrapper Calling assignDocID
2024-05-28 03:21:29,929, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] INFO  UploadDocMDBDelegate Entered storeDocument for PolicyNumber: MN0097451 for QuoteID: **Validation passed**Document stored at docStore: GI with repositoryKey: 7f3e34707d37403ba06e8bd668ae865f**OacrSourceSystem:AK**OacrBussinessAppType:BO**OacrBussinessProcessType:AAAS**ReturnCode: 200**ReturnMessage: Success!
2024-05-28 03:21:29,929, [MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] ERROR UploadDocMDBBean Exception thrown in com.adn.commonServicePlatform.uploadDoc.UploadDocMDBBean in method onMessage(Message msg)javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout

Application is deployed in websphere application server and I have configured connection pool of every datasources timeout, still getting the error.
Kindly help, how can I solve this error.

Check out timeout in the "Transaction service" in WebSphere. There are global timeouts defined there for distributed transactions.
